# Is it possible to set Android apps to connect to dev servers?

Tags: android, dns, testing, resolve

When building desktop or web apps, its easy to add fake hosts file entries so apps will connect to dev servers instead of production ones - is something similar possible for Android apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't edit the /etc/hosts file on most Android devices, since you normally don't have root access.

A better option is to just build a preference into your application that allows you to specify which server your application can use when establishing it's connection.

Comment: Is it possible to check if an app is being debugged and switch hostnames that way?

Comment: Yes. See android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected(): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#isDebuggerConnected()